# Bash get lines from text file by reading line numbers from another file

Tags: bash

I have a file *lines.txt* of the following type:

```
1
3
5
6
```

And I have another file *text.txt* of the following type:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

I want to get an output file containing:

```
A
C
E
F
```

Is there any bash command which would help me do that?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No it's not. I am able to get it through a python script but I'm curious as to how to do it in bash.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Show us some code. Otherwise, questions requesting tools or libraries are explicitly off-topic on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the line numbers in `lines.txt` and then use `sed` the required lines:

```
for line in `cat lines.txt`
do
  sed -n "${line}p" text.txt
done
```

Comment: Another way: `while read line; do sed -n "${line}p" text.txt; done<lines.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can number the lines from `text.txt` by `cat -n`. Then you can use `join` to pair the two files based on the numbers, `-o2.2` means *show the second column from the second file*.

```
cat -n text.txt | join -o2.2 lines.txt -
```

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> - use [nl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nl) utility to number the lines
> - use [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) to join based on line number key

**example**

```
join -o 1.2 <( nl -n ln text.txt ) lines.txt
```

**output**

```
A
C
E
F
```